# How to calculate Image Size in JS or jQuery or JAVA?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, image

I need to calculate the size of an image. I've an image src and base64 data also. I want to show the current image size.
I'm using java and javascript.
Is there any option using which I can calculate size of the image?

Comment: Size in terms of pixel dimensions, or bytes?

Comment: Are you talking about the file size (e.g., 1.2 MB) or the image dimensions (e.g., 600x400 px)?

Comment: Which is it? Java or Javascript? The only similarities between the two are the letters J, a, and v.

Comment: Size in terms of bytes. Meaning the file size.

Comment: @NickJ it might be that Java is used on server side. Nevertheless. the question is quite uncleared one.

Comment: @NickJ Well,both can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `p = object.fileSize` for file size

and for image dimension

```
var image= document.getElementById('imageId'); 
var width = image.clientWidth;
var height = image.clientHeight;
```

the best way you can use is :

```
var obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
obj.open('HEAD', 'check-image-load.zip', true);
obj.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if ( obj.readyState == 4 ) {
if ( obj.status == 200 ) {
alert('Size in bytes: ' + obj.getResponseHeader('Content-Length'));
} else { alert('ERROR'); } }};
obj.send(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **`javascript`** you do it this way...

Bind the `load` event and when that particular `src` loads, just fetch `this.width` and `this.height` to have `width` and `height` of image.

```
    var imgLoad = $("<img />");
    imgLoad.attr("src", yourSrc);
    imgLoad.unbind("load");
    imgLoad.bind("load", function () {

    var width = this.width;
    var height = this.height;
    });
```